# How to get Location header when URL redirected using Invoke-WebRequest in powershell

Tags: powershell, redirect, header, location, invoke-webrequest

- Calling a URL which permanently moved or redirected, does not return Location http header or the correct location.
- it seems that URL redirection is being performed during URL call ( http status code :  302, 301 etc ).

How do I overcome this ?

Answer (score 5):

Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574479/powershell-determine-new-url-of-a-permanently-moved-redirected-resource) by **Alec Collier**

Add the following to your URL call :  **-MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction Ignore**

Example :

```
$url="https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html"

$resp = Invoke-WebRequest $url -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction Ignore

$resp.Headers.Location
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `-MaximumRedirection 0 -SkipHttpErrorCheck` (and add `-ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue` if you want to suppress the warning):

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.google.com/ncr" -MaximumRedirection 0 -SkipHttpErrorCheck -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue).Headers.Location

https://www.google.com/
```

Note that the data type of return value is an array and it only has a single item.